# Find, if it exists, a quintic curve in $A^{2}$ over complex numbers, with the following conditions:

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

- The curve has two asymptotes, $x + 3y - 2 = 0$ and $x + 3 y - 3 = 0$
- The curve has a two degree inflation point in $(0,0)$, with inflational tangent $x + 3 y = 0$ (Sorry if the terminology is not proper, I’m translating. I mean that the origin is a simple point, but the inflational tangent has order of intersection of 4 with the curve there).

If the curve doesn’t exist, explain why.

My doubts come from the fact that I know the sum of the intersection orders of the curve with any line needs to be equal or less than the degree of the curve, it can’t be equal if the improper (infinite) point of the line is not an infinite point of the curve. I know by the two asymptotes being parallel that the lines share the same infinite point that is the same of the curve, since by definition they’re tangent there when I submerge the affine space into the projective one. If the intersection order is preserved when I change from affine equations to projective ones, the problem may be easier, but as of now I’m clueless. Can anybody help me? Thank you.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand all of what you wrote, but you can indeed show that the tangent line to the curve at the origin meets the curve in multiplicity at least 6: multiplicity four at the origin by assumption, and multiplicity at least two at infinity, since the point $[3:-1:0]$ has two tangents and is therefore singular (and intersection multiplicity of a line and a singular point is at least two). (Could "inflation"/"inflational" mean "inflection/"inflectional"?)

Comment: Yes, sorry, definitely not an English speaker lol. So the line x + 3y = 0, when looked at in the projective plane, meets the point P with multiplicity at least two, and what you’re saying is that the multiplicity of the intersection carries over from affine to projective plane, right? So [1,0,0] is a inflational point of second degree for the projective closure of the curve?

Comment: Don't worry too much, you're doing an admirable job with the English. Yes, if $C,C'\subset\Bbb P^2$ are two curves, then the intersection multiplicity of $C$ and $C'$ at a point $P\in\Bbb A^2$ is the same as the intersection multiplicity of $C\cap \Bbb A^2$ and $C'\cap\Bbb A^2$ considered as affine curves at $P$.